# National Instruments Teststand Property Loader

Tags: sequence, teststand

I had some problems with Property Loader, let me describe.

I have MainSequence with several subsequences. I have to load file with test limits according to scanned number using property Loader. I moved this loading from PreUUTLoop to MainSequence because only then I have access to scanned number which is determining wwhich file to use.

The limit files contains limits depending on scanned number. Defined limits refer to steps in MainSequence and in other subsequences.

What I noticed is that the Property Loader works fine when put in MainSequence (no difference if in Setup or Main). But when I put Property Loader in seperate subsequnce(and put subseq in Setup or Main of MainSequence) it loads only limits for Subsequences in MainSequence. Limits for steps(i.e numeric check) directly in MainSequence are not loaded.

In limit file I have sth like this:

```
START_SubSeq1
<step_name> Limit.High Limit.Low
Step1       10         0
END_SubSeq1
START_SubSeq2
<step_name> Limit.High Limit.Low
Step1       20         0
END_SubSeq2
START_MainSequence
<step_name> Limit.High Limit.Low
Step3       40         0
END_MainSequence
```

MainSequence looks like this:

```
()Setup
  Call SetLimits
()Main
  Call Subseq2
  Call Subseq1
  Step3 Numeric check GELE
()CleanUp
```

SetLimits:

```
()Setup
()Main
  If(scnanedNumber==1)
   PropertyLoader(file1)
  Else
   PropertyLoader(file2)
()CleanUp
```

SubSeq1:

```
()Setup
()Main
  Step1 Numeric check GELE
()CleanUp
```

SubSeq2:

```
()Setup
()Main
  Step1 Numeric check GELE
()CleanUp
```

So Step1 in SubSeq1 is set as in file. Step1 in SubSeq2 is also set but Step3 is not set when Property Loader is in Subseq.
I tried in Property Loader tick the use for current Execusion but does not work.
I thought it is some range issue but steps in other subsequences are set. It happens only if I want to set sth in MainSequence from Property Loader in Subsequence.

I use NI Teststand 2014. Parallel model. Numeric checks steps are Teststand default modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here:
[NI forum](http://forums.ni.com/t5/NI-TestStand/Property-Loader-in-sub-sequence-doesn-t-change-MainSequence/td-p/3004423)

Solution:
put Property Loader in PreUUT/PreUUTLoop or in a new Custom Callback after PreUUTLoop.